# How to read excel using Infragistics WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I have excel where in Sheet 1 i have 2 tables ,i want to read data by infragistics WPF and bind in UI below is the structure of data in excel , i am new to WPF can anyone help

[image: gistics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the methods to read the Excel file is using the `XamSpreadsheet` control that allows visualizing and editing of spreadsheet data.

There is the code example.

```
using Infragistics.Documents.Excel;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Resources;

namespace ReadExcelFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadFile();        
        }

        private void LoadFile()
        {
            // For this example the excel document is located in resources
            var fileName = "/ReadExcelFile;component/Resources/Book1.xlsx";
            Stream stream = GetFileAsStream(fileName);            
            if (Workbook.Load(stream) is Workbook wb)
            {
                this.xamSpreadsheet1.Workbook = wb;
                this.Title = "Book1.xlsx";
            }
        }

        public static Stream GetFileAsStream(string fullName)
        {
            StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fullName, UriKind.Relative));
            return sri.Stream;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ReadExcelFile.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Grid>
        <ig:XamSpreadsheet x:Name="xamSpreadsheet1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The application will looks like on the screenshot:
[image]

It is necessary add references to the following assemblies:

- InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Grids.XamSpreadsheet
- InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel

For additional information see: [XamSpreadsheet](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/spreadsheet)